# Q: Getting a File's MD5 Checksum in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, swift2

Let's say I want to get the checksum for `bash` located in the `/bin` directory of OSX using Swift 2.x. For my version of OSX, the MD5 is

```
 5d7583d80e5314ac844eedc6d68c6cd7
```

I calculated it using `md5 bash`. I also verified it using an [online tool](http://onlinemd5.com).

I decided to use CommonCrypto since it looks like it may have a speed advantage over [other options at this time](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/issues/30). When I run my code I get a different result:

```
bash: d574d4bb40c84861791a694a999cce69
```

Any help would be appreciated. The contents of both the bridging-header and AppDelegate are below.

**md5-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import Cocoa

extension String {
    func md5() -> String! {
        let str = self.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let strLen = CUnsignedInt(self.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        let digestLen = Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(digestLen)

        CC_MD5(str!, strLen, result)

        let hash = NSMutableString()
        for i in 0..<digestLen {
            hash.appendFormat("%02x", result[i])
        }

        result.destroy()

        return String(format: hash as String)
    }
}



@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let path = "/bin"
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)
        for item in items {
            print("\(item): " + item.md5())
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? You compute the MD5 hash of the *file names* in the bin directory. "d574d4bb40c84861791a694a999cce69" is the MD5 hash of the string "bash". You nowhere read the file contents.

Comment: What does `md5 -s bash` give you? ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think your program calculates the MD5 of the String `"bash"`, but not of content of the file named **bash**.

Comment: More coffee needed. Thanks!